# Haskell Removing database variable without changing code

Tags: database, variables, haskell

I have just realised I have been going by this incorrectly.

I have created functions that relate to a `testDatabase`. I have also included this in the function however, I want to change this so the functional code can run with any database later and not just relate to `testDatabase` as a few of the functions are doing now.

By removing `testDatabase` from some of the functions I would get errors hence just need some help to alter and fix this and for future reference. I've learnt my  lesson not to use the actual testing database in functions.

How can I alter my code so that `testDatabase` is not in the functional, but in the demo it relates to it similar to demos 1, 7 and 77.

I have no problem changing the code completely, but I am just looking for a quick fix.

I hope I have explained this correctly.

```
import Data.List 
import Text.Printf
import Data.Ord
import Data.Char

type Rating = (String, Int)
type Title = String
type Director = String
type Year = Int
type Film = (Title, Director, Year,[Rating])

testDatabase :: [Film]
testDatabase = [("Blade Runner","Ridley Scott",1982,[("Amy",6), ("Bill",9), ("Ian",7), ("Kevin",9), ("Emma",4), ("Sam",5), ("Megan",4)]),
                ("The Fly","David Cronenberg",1986,[("Megan",4), ("Fred",7), ("Chris",5), ("Ian",0), ("Amy",5)]),
                ("Psycho","Alfred Hitchcock",1960,[("Bill",4), ("Jo",4), ("Garry",8), ("Kevin",7), ("Olga",8), ("Liz",10), ("Ian",9)]),
                ("Body Of Lies","Ridley Scott",2008,[("Sam",3), ("Neal",7), ("Kevin",2), ("Chris",5), ("Olga",6)]),
                ("Avatar","James Cameron",2009,[("Olga",2), ("Wally",8), ("Megan",9), ("Tim",5), ("Zoe",8), ("Emma",3)]),
                ("Titanic","James Cameron",1997,[("Zoe",7), ("Amy",2), ("Emma",5), ("Heidi",3), ("Jo",8), ("Megan",5), ("Olga",7), ("Tim",10)]),
                ("The Departed","Martin Scorsese",2006,[("Heidi",2), ("Jo",8), ("Megan",5), ("Tim",2), ("Fred",5)]),
                ("Aliens","Ridley Scott",1986,[("Fred",8), ("Dave",6), ("Amy",10), ("Bill",7), ("Wally",2), ("Zoe",5)]),
                ("Prometheus","Ridley Scott",2012,[("Garry",3), ("Chris",4), ("Emma",5), ("Bill",1), ("Dave",3)]),
                ("E.T. The Extra-Terrestrial","Steven Spielberg",1982,[("Ian",7), ("Amy",2), ("Emma",7), ("Sam",8), ("Wally",5), ("Zoe",6)]),
                ("The Birds","Alfred Hitchcock",1963,[("Garry",7), ("Kevin",9), ("Olga",4), ("Tim",7), ("Wally",3)]),
                ("Goodfellas","Martin Scorsese",1990,[("Emma",7), ("Sam",9), ("Wally",5), ("Dave",3)]),
                ("The Shawshank Redemption","Frank Darabont",1994,[("Jo",8), ("Sam",10), ("Zoe",3), ("Dave",7), ("Emma",3), ("Garry",10), ("Kevin",7)]),
                ("Gladiator","Ridley Scott",2000,[("Garry",7), ("Ian",4), ("Neal",6), ("Wally",3), ("Emma",4)]),
                ("The Green Mile","Frank Darabont",1999,[("Sam",3), ("Zoe",4), ("Dave",8), ("Wally",5), ("Jo",5)]),
                ("True Lies","James Cameron",1994,[("Dave",3), ("Kevin",4), ("Jo",0)]),
                ("Minority Report","Steven Spielberg",2002,[("Dave",5), ("Garry",6), ("Megan",2), ("Sam",7), ("Wally",8)]),
                ("The Wolf of Wall Street","Martin Scorsese",2013,[("Dave",6), ("Garry",6), ("Megan",0), ("Sam",4)]),
                ("War Horse","Steven Spielberg",2011,[("Dave",6), ("Garry",6), ("Megan",3), ("Sam",7), ("Wally",8), ("Zoe",8)]),
                ("Lincoln","Steven Spielberg",2012,[("Ian",3), ("Sam",7), ("Wally",3), ("Zoe",4), ("Liz",7), ("Megan",4)]),
                ("Vertigo","Alfred Hitchcock",1958,[("Bill",7), ("Emma",5), ("Zoe",9), ("Olga",6), ("Tim",10)]),
                ("The Terminal","Steven Spielberg",2004,[("Olga",3), ("Heidi",8), ("Bill",2), ("Sam",6), ("Garry",8)]),
                ("Jaws","Steven Spielberg",1975,[("Fred",3), ("Garry",0), ("Jo",3), ("Neal",9), ("Emma",7)]),
                ("Hugo","Martin Scorsese",2011,[("Sam",4), ("Wally",3), ("Zoe",4), ("Liz",7)])] 

------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------FUNCTIONAL CODE----------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------                

--when adding need to be addFilm string string int and the list name called testDatabase 
addFilm :: String -> String -> Int -> [Film] -> [Film]
addFilm title director year database = (title, director, year, [])  : database  

--Some functions needed later on:
averageFilmRating :: [(String,Int)] -> Float
averageFilmRating ratings
     = (fromIntegral(sum $ map snd ratings)) / (fromIntegral(length ratings))

--Formats the films for decimal, gives average rating of films instead of all users ratings.
formatFilmOutput :: Film -> String
formatFilmOutput (title, director, year, rating)
     = printf "%s by %s. Year: %d, Average Rating: %.1f\n" (title) (director) (year) (averageFilmRating rating)

--Shows all films in the database    
displayAllFilm :: [Film] -> [Film]
displayAllFilm list = list


--Shows films by director name
displayByDirector :: String -> [Film]
displayByDirector name
     =  filter(\(_,director,_,_) -> director == name) testDatabase

--Gives the average of directors films  
directorAverage :: String -> Float
directorAverage dir
     = averageFilmRating [rating | (title, director, year, ratings) <- displayByDirector dir, rating <- ratings]

--These two functions give the films rated of average 6 or over  
filmsRated :: Int -> [Film]
filmsRated rating
         = filter(\(_,_,_,a) -> averageFilmRating a >= fromIntegral rating) testDatabase 

filmsaveragesix = filmsRated 6  

--Shows what films the user has rated.
userRatedFilms :: String -> [Film]
userRatedFilms username
     = filter ((username `elem`) . (\(_,_,_,xs) -> map fst xs)) testDatabase

-- Allows user to rate or re-rate film.
databaseNoFilm:: [Film] -> Title -> [Film]
databaseNoFilm database t = [(title, director, year, ratings) | (title, director, year, ratings) <- database, title /= t]
rateFilm :: [Film] -> Title -> Rating -> [Film]
rateFilm database findtitle (u, r) = databaseNoFilm database findtitle ++ [(title,director,year,(u, r):[(username,rtg) | (username,rtg) <- ratings, username /= u]) | (title, director, year, ratings) <- database, title == findtitle] 

--Displays films by year in descending order of rating
filmsByYear :: Int -> [Film]
filmsByYear year = sortFilms $ filter(\(_,_,yr,_) -> yr >= year) testDatabase

sortFilms :: [Film] -> [Film]
sortFilms = sortBy $ flip $ comparing averageFilmRating'
  where
    averageFilmRating' (_,_,_,rs) = averageFilmRating rs

------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------DEMO FUNCTION------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------
demo :: Int -> IO ()
demo choice = do
    case choice of
        1 -> do
            putStrLn $ unlines $ map formatFilmOutput $ addFilm "Gravity" "Alfonso Cuaron" 2013 testDatabase
        2 -> do
            putStrLn (unlines $ map formatFilmOutput $ displayAllFilm testDatabase)
        3 -> do
            putStrLn (unlines (map formatFilmOutput(displayByDirector "James Cameron")))
        4 -> do
            putStrLn (unlines (map formatFilmOutput(filmsaveragesix)))
        5 -> do
            print $ directorAverage "James Cameron"
        6 -> do
            print $ userRatedFilms "Zoe"
        7 -> do
            print $ rateFilm testDatabase "Jaws" ("Zoe", 8)
        77 -> do
            print $ rateFilm testDatabase "Vertigo" ("Zoe", 3)          
        8 -> do
            putStrLn (unlines (map formatFilmOutput(filmsByYear 2009)))
```

Comment: You need to use a `State` monad in `demo` and use for example `modify` (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-1.1.0.2/docs/Control-Monad-State-Class.html#v:modify) to change the state and `get` to feed the state through. For the functions that currently access `testDatabase` directly, you'll also need to make it an argument.

Comment: PS some of your `type` synonyms could benefit *heaps* from being records, or at least, `newtype`s (since `type` is not as "safe").

Comment: I dont think what you're saying is necessary. Im sure there is a simpler way i just cant think of it at the moment. Maybe i need a data constructor?

Comment: I think I misunderstood. Only the last part of my first comment is still relevant, I think.. I find it puzzling you're not able to do this simple refractor yourself.

Comment: @kvanberendonck I will have a go at making the functions which access it directly as arguments. Just seem to get confused on reading the errors in Haskell. A way to get me started would help massively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send testDatabase as a parameter. For example:

```
--Displays films by year in descending order of rating
filmsByYear :: Int -> [Film] -> [Film]
filmsByYear year database = sortFilms $ filter(\(_,_,yr,_) -> yr >= year) database
```

Then add `testDatabase` to any code calling this function:

```
putStrLn (unlines (map formatFilmOutput(filmsByYear 2009 testDatabase)))
```

Do the same in `userRatedFilms` and `displayByDirector`.

Comment: This is initially what i did and got error'd so asked here. It seems i forgot the parameter [Film]. Such a silly mistake! Thanks  for your help!